# Why doesn't Ruby 'require' allow relative paths?

Tags: ruby

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314237/why-relative-path-doesnt-work-in-ruby-require) sort of answers the question by claiming that `require` will only search relative to the path that the script was run in. But this really does not **appear** to be true. I will elaborate.

I created a quick C extension and compiled it to `mytest.so`. Then, in the same directory I fired up `irb`.

```
irb(main):009:0> require 'mytest.so'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- mytest.so
```

This is expected because the claim in the other answer is that `require` is searching relative to where `irb` was run from. In my case that would be `/usr/bin/irb`. So I tried the `required_relative` solution from the other question:

```
irb(main):006:0> require_relative './mytest.so'
LoadError: cannot infer basepath
```

No luck. And FYI - `mytest.so` is tab-completing here so `irb` is clearly aware it is in the current working directory. Furthermore, I can easily prove this:

```
irb(main):004:0> system("pwd")
/home/mike/Documents/ruby_test
# => true
irb(main):005:0> File.expand_path("./")
# => "/home/mike/Documents/ruby_test"
```

Okay final test, I will assume that `irb` is being executed in `/usr/bin` **despite** the evidence pointing against that.

```
irb(main):011:0> require '../../home/mike/Documents/ruby_test/mytest.so'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- ../../home/mike/Documents/ruby_test/mytest.so
```

I would greatly appreciate if anyone can shed some light on what is going on with `require`?

BTW, I am aware I can **solve** this issue by giving the exact file path. This question is about trying understand what is happening beneath the surface.

```
require '/home/mike/Documents/ruby_test/mytest.so' # this works
```

Comment: I am speculating, but I am thinking that you got a close vote because of the statement and opinion that it is "so baffling" but if you remove that or change it to baffling you, as opposed to generally baffling, then it is no longer an opinion... :)

Comment: @vgoff thanks for the advice, i removed that part

Comment: I'm curious if `require './mytest.so` works? This usually works for me from irb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr: IRB is special and has some odd rules. Ruby in general works just fine with relative paths.

`require` will search the load path (which you can see by inspecting `$:` or `$LOAD_PATH`). This will not include the directory that you launched IRB from:

```
> $:
 => ["/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-head/lib/ruby/2.2/site_ruby", "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-head/lib/ruby/stdlib"]
```

So there's no joy there, unless you explicitly add your directory to the load path. This is what Rubygems and Bundler spends most of their time doing - they manage the load paths for gems so you don't have to worry about it. However, this doesn't help you with single files.

Additionally, `require_relative` will search from the directory that `__FILE__` is in, but in IRB, this is a non-directory `(irb)` value! This is why you get the "can't infer basepath" issue when trying `require_relative` from IRB; since the currently executing file, `__FILE__`, isn't a proper path, `require_relative` can't figure out where to start from.

When you are not running from IRB, this isn't really an issue; `require_relative 'mytest.so'` should work just fine when you execute it in a script, since the currently-executing script will populate `__FILE__`. That is, if you have `loader.rb` and `mytest.so` and execute loader via `ruby loader.rb`, `require_relative` should work just fine.

If you want to run this in IRB, consider something like:

```
require "#{__dir__}/mytest.so"
```

which will expand out to the current working directory, which should by default be the directory you've launched it from. I would recommend that you not do this in a script, though, since it depends on `__dir__` not having been changed, and that may be difficult to guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-require):

> Loads the given name, returning true if successful and false if the
>   feature is already loaded.
>
> If the filename does not resolve to an absolute path, it will be
>   searched for in the directories listed in $LOAD_PATH ($:).
>
> If the filename has the extension “.rb”, it is loaded as a source
>   file; if the extension is “.so”, “.o”, or “.dll”, or the default
>   shared library extension on the current platform, Ruby loads the
>   shared library as a Ruby extension. Otherwise, Ruby tries adding
>   “.rb”, “.so”, and so on to the name until found. If the file named
>   cannot be found, a LoadError will be raised.
>
> For Ruby extensions the filename given may use any shared library
>   extension. For example, on Linux the socket extension is “socket.so”
>   and require 'socket.dll' will load the socket extension.
>
> The absolute path of the loaded file is added to $LOADED_FEATURES
>   ($"). A file will not be loaded again if its path already appears in
>   $". For example, require 'a'; require './a' will not load a.rb again.

---

The answer to your question is that it simply isn't designed to.

You could use `require_relative` if you want to require files relative to your files' path.

You could add your projects library folder to the `$LOAD_PATH` to get the functionality you are asking for, that is, `require 'my_library'`

In IRB for loading local files, you may want to use `load` instead, as it gives you the ability to load file/library multiple times, where `require` will load the file/library only once.  The `__FILE__` variable works in IRB just like it should.  It is the identification of the file (in this case the open process) in which the variable is invoked.